# How to get the page table content of a process in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, memory, module, page-tables

I'm trying to display top-level page table of a process that I created.

How can I get the page table content of a process inside a module I write in Linux?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS virtual machine on a Windows 8 host with 64-bit Intel architecture.

Comment: I think it's in `/proc/PID/pagemap`. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though i don't know the exact answer for your question and I have been looking for the same. The sum of my research so for is as below:

1. you should consult the process descriptor which contains link to the memory descriptor (mm_struct). if you check the memory descriptor it contains very good information how process is using the memory. i think for your problem check pgd which is a pointer to the global page directory of the process.
2. hopefully your written module would be a virtualization driver if so then also check the mmap_base field of the memory descriptor

if you already know the answer please share here; i am looking the same